# Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $n$ be an integer not divisible by $p-1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $n$ be an integer not divisible by $p-1$.
Show that $\sum x^n \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, when the sum is over all $x$ with $0\le x\le p-1$.

Some help with this practice problem?

Comment: Do you know that if $p$ is prime there's a primitive root modulo $p$?

Comment: Yes, of course, but I don't see how that helps.

Comment: So you can express each $x$ as $g^r$, where $g$ is your primitive root, and $r$ depends on $x$.

Comment: How are we doing? Get something out of Barry Smith's answer?

Comment: Source of the problem: exercise 2.6 in solving mathematical problems terence tao

Answer (score 4):

Do you know about primitive roots yet?  If so, let $r$ be a primitive root modulo $p$.  Then the nonzero $x$'s in your sum are in some order congruent to $r^0$, $r^1$, $\ldots$, $r^{p-2}$ modulo $p$. So, replace the terms of your sum with these powers of $r$ that are congruent to them. Rearranging the terms, if necessary, you find your sum is congruent to

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{p-2} r^{in} $$

modulo $p$.  This is a geometric series.  The usual formula for a finite geometric series is valid if the division is considered instead to be "multiplying the numerator by the multiplicative inverse of the element in the denominator".  As long as $n$ is not divisible by $p-1$, this element is invertible and the numerator is congruent to $0$ modulo $p$.  (These are things to check).

Finish up by checking the case where $n$ is divisible by $p-1$ directly.  You will find Fermat's Little Theorem useful throughout this work.